# How to keep the subsection counter when using \part in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, sectioning, parts

I'm using Beamer to create my lecture notes. I'm using `\part{}` to separate individual lectures. However, I find out that if a part starts with a subsection, then the subsection counter is automatically reset. How can I avoid this?

Here is a minimal running example. The subsection counter in the second part is reset as 1, which is supposed to be 3.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme[width = 1.5cm, height = 1cm]{sidebar}
\begin{document}


%=================== Lecture 1 ======================
\part{}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1.1}
\subsection{subsection 1.2}
\section{section 2}
\subsection{subsection 2.1}
\subsection{subsection 2.2}
\begin{frame}{Page 1}
     The section counter in Part \thepart is \thesection.\\
     The subsection counter in Part \thepart is \thesubsection.
\end{frame}


\part{}
\subsection{subsection 2.3}
\begin{frame}{Page 2}
    The section counter in Part \thepart is \thesection.\\
     The subsection counter in Part \thepart is \thesubsection.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Copied from the duplicate question https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/611

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[width = 1.5cm, height = 1cm]{sidebar}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand<>{\part}{\alt#1{\@dblarg\beamer@part}{\beamer@gobbleoptional}}
\long\def\beamer@part[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode
  \mode<all>%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture
    \refstepcounter{part}%
    \def\beamer@partname{#2}%
    \def\beamer@partnameshort{#1}%
    \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\partentry{#2}{\the\c@part}}}%
    \xdef\partlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\beamer@partname}}%
    \xdef\partlinkshort{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\beamer@partnameshort}}%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
        \protect\beamer@partpages{\the\beamer@partstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
    \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
        \protect\beamer@sectionpages{\the\beamer@sectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
    \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{%
        \protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
    \beamer@partstartpage=\c@page
    \beamer@sectionstartpage=\c@page
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page
%    \setcounter{subsection}{0}%
    \protected\def\insertsection{}%
    \protected\def\insertsubsection{}%
    \protected\def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \protected\def\insertsectionhead{}%
    \protected\def\insertsubsectionhead{}%
    \protected\def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\lastsubsection{}%
    \protected\def\insertpart{\expandafter\hyperlink\partlink}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@part}{#1}{Outline\the\c@part}{1}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part}\hyper@anchorend
    \beamer@atbeginpart
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}


%=================== Lecture 1 ======================
\part{}
\section{section 1}
\subsection{subsection 1.1}
\subsection{subsection 1.2}
\section{section 2}
\subsection{subsection 2.1}
\subsection{subsection 2.2}
\begin{frame}{Page 1}
     The section counter in Part \thepart is \thesection.\\
     The subsection counter in Part \thepart is \thesubsection.
\end{frame}


\part{}
\subsection{subsection 2.3}
\begin{frame}{Page 2}
    The section counter in Part \thepart is \thesection.\\
     The subsection counter in Part \thepart is \thesubsection.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this one !

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Hannover}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[sections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsection in toc}[subsections numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{subsubsection in toc}[subsubsections numbered]
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Titre}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section{Rappels}
\subsection{Fondements}
\begin{frame}{Titre}
Bla bla.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Titre}
Bla bla.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Titre}
Bla bla.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Implications}
\begin{frame}{Titre}
Bla bla.
\end{frame}
\subsection{Critiques}
\begin{frame}{Titre}
Bla bla.
\end{frame}
\section{Th\'eorie}
\subsection{Plan}
\begin{frame}{Titre}
Bla bla.
\end{frame}
\subsection{\'Equilibre}
\begin{frame}{Titre}
Bla bla.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
Haut
```